# Php Array result in plain text

Tags: php, arrays, plaintext

I want to get the array result in a plain text area and each result separated with " , ".

**PHP codes :**

- `$nbrs = json_decode(fBGetDataStore('neighbors'), true);`
- `<?= count($nbrs) ?>` (to count `$nbrs`)
- `print_r($nbrs)` (to get FBID `$nbrs`)

**The results :**

```
FBID of Your available Nbrz: Array
(
    [242] => 100001358797416,
    [243] => 100000859795350,
    [244] => 100000843343992,
    [247] => 100000257661280,
    [248] => 100000351371568,
    [249] => 1349056951,
    [251] => 100000805381194,
)
1
```

This is the result I want:

```
FBID of Your available Nbrz:

100000348365067,100005373581538
```

Comment: `implode($nbrs);` http://php.net/implode

Comment: no 2 is incomplete making correction " counting $nbrs i'm using " <?= count($nbrs) ?> "

Comment: implode($nbrs) is worked but i want separate each figure with comma .. right now the results are http://prntscr.com/6tbwk6
@cmorrissey

Comment: read the docs with the link i provided above!

Comment: Thank you so much @cmorrissey done it http://prntscr.com/6tc01d
Result http://prntscr.com/6tc0l7

Comment: Friendly advice: you really need to put more effort into the creation of your question. Don't give us your code as images on an external site. Instead, include it in your question and format it properly.

Comment: sure i'll @cascaval and sorry for now i'm new here

Comment: I know you are new and that's why I'm giving you the advice. If you want good answers, you need to come come up with a good question. A good question is the one which is clear, easy to comprehend and states what you expect and what you have tried. The reason why you are being downvoted is because your question doesn't meet this.

Comment: thank you once again and i will try my best in future .

Comment: I edited your question to include the screen shots as inline code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try:

```
$nbrs = implode(",",$nbrs);
```

#### Docs: http://php.net/implode